# How to invoke a function by using same thing but in elsewhere, usingReflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

So this is my plugin/external object

```
namespace Outer
{
    interface IMonster
    {
        String GetName();
    }
    interface IPlugin
    {
        String GetGameVersion();
        long GetPureTime();
        IMonster GetMonster(int iEntityIndex);
    }

    abstract class TheHack
    {
        public abstract void OnEnabled(IPlugin pluginInterface);
        public abstract void OnDisabled();
    }

    class Plugin : TheHack
    {
        public override void OnEnabled(IPlugin pluginInterface)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pluginInterface.GetMonster(0).GetName());
        }

        public override void OnDisabled()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Plugin disabled");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my internal code that grabs the Plugin assembly, create a new Outer class instance and execute it, and pass the global plugin object from my internal code, into the class instance.

```
namespace Inner
{
    interface IMonster
    {
        String GetName();
    }
    interface IPlugin
    {
        String GetGameVersion();
        long GetPureTime();
        IMonster GetMonster(int iEntityIndex);
    }
    abstract class TheHack
    {
        public abstract void OnEnabled(IPlugin pluginInterface);
        public abstract void OnDisabled();
    }
    class ImplMonster : IMonster
    {
        public String GetName()
        {
            return "A cute cat";
        }
    }
    class Impl: IPlugin
    {
        public String GetGameVersion()
        {
            return "-1";
        }

        public long GetPureTime()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        }

        public IMonster GetMonster(int iEntityIndex)
        {
            return new ImplMonster();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           var tp = Assembly.Load("plugin.dll").GetType("Outer.Plugin");
           if (tp != null)
           {
               var cls = Activator.CreateInstance(tp);

               MethodInfo mi = tp.GetMethod("OnEnabled", new[] {typeof (IPlugin)});

               if (mi != null && tp.IsSubclassOf(typeof (TheHack)))
               {
                  mi.Invoke(cls, new[] {new Implementation()});
               }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I was debugging these code, there's no result on the console, so I decided to pull off the null protection code, but the debugger told me that the objects in Inner cannot be applied to Outer, but they extends, implemented the same class, same structure, but the debugger just telling me that it cannot be run.

Why would this happen, and how to ignore/bypass the check, because I wanted to make a plugin system, where I could manipulate the pure virtual method to achieve this in C++, but in C#, there is no same relevant(there no pure virtual function in C#, thought abstract function was a akin to but type safe, and I cannot pass memory address cause I'm not running unsafe code) nor any similar ways to do this.

Comment: This code works absolutely correctly - Inner.IPlugin and Outer.IPlugin are completely different types and you can't use them interchangeably. I am not sure what you really want to achieve(dynamic duck typed plugins without shared types?), but standard way to create plugins in .NET differs a bit - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972962.aspx, http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/546639/How-to-create-an-easy-plugin-system-in-Csharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've defined every type twice: once in the plugin, once in the main executable. That's the only way to go in some other environments, but it's not going to work in C#. Even if the types have the exact same namespace, and the exact same name, if they come from different assemblies, they're distinct types.

What you should instead do is define the base types *only* in the main executable. In the plugin, add a reference to the main executable, and you'll be able to reference the main executable's public types and derive from them.

Comment: No, I wanted the developer to reference the plugin prototype library only, because the main executable would be obfuscated in order to protect against hackers to steal my code.

Comment: @SteveFan If you can't tell your obfuscator to ignore specific types that must be externally accessible, then what would still work is putting it in a common DLL that's referenced by both your main executable and by the plugins.